# Transformations between coordinate frames

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

Suppose I have three coordinate frames: $A$, $B$ and $C$, all in 2D space. In homogeneous coordinates, I deduce, by inspection, the transformation matrices between each of these ($T_{AB}$, $T_{BC}$ and $T_{AC}$). However, when I calculate $T_{AC}$ analytically, by computing $T_{AC} = T_{AB} * T_{BC}$, I get a different answer to the value of $T_{AC}$ I got by inspection.

Below is an example of this. I'm sure there is something very stupid and simple I am doing wrong, but it's very confusing. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure those aren't 3D rotation matrices? $T_{AC}$ should be something like $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$. Instead, if we allow a z-axis, but just ignore it, since the third row and column refer to the relationships with the z-axis, you can easily see that any vector of the form $\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
v_x\\ 
v_y\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ will transform the same way with your $T_{AC}$ or with $T_{AB} T_{BC}$.

Comment: Luigi, they are Homogeneous coordinats.

Comment: Your transformations dont look right.  In your notation $T_{AB}, is that from A to B or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Use a version of [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) and the idea of linear independence. Then subtracting column 1 from column 3 twice, and adding column 2 to column 3 twice results in your expected output.